# Listing names of Excel files from URL using Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am trying to do web scraping using Python and BeautifulSoup, so going through tutorials, but I am stuck after successful `requests.get(url)`.

As soon as I define the elements which I want to extract (names of Excel file names appearing on the website) based on tag  and its class, which contains string of "file-id-..." (... means id of the files) all I get an empty list.

My goal is to list all Excel file names from this url address, and basically open them later by using for loop. All of it, to extract specific monthly data from national labour office, which have the same structure throughout the year.

```
labour_office_web_text = requests.get("url").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(labour_office_web_text, "lxml")
file_names = soup.find_all('a[class*="file-id-"]')
file_names
```

Any recommendations? Thank you!

Comment: try `file_names = soup.find_all('a', {"class":"file-id-"})`. And I guess you will need to get `text`  or `href` of each tag.

Comment: Could you provide the URL? Or add enough HTML to your question to enable us to recreate the problem

Comment: Sure @MartinEvans, here is the URL [link](https://www.upsvr.gov.sk/statistiky/nezamestnanost-mesacne-statistiky/2020.html?page_id=971502)

In the mean time I tried to get all `href` of tags from the url and `search` for ones which contains .xlsx suffix. Then `append` them to the created list.
`file_links = soup.find_all(href=True)
file_links

list_of_links = []
sufix=".xlsx"
for el in file_links:
  link=el["href"]
  if search(sufix,link):
    list_of_links.append(link)

list_of_links`
thanks @buran for an advice! Feel free to recommend better approach, I am new to programming

Comment: It's usually easier just to use the [edit] button to add any new information to the question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all `.xls` links from that page you can use next example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.upsvr.gov.sk/statistiky/nezamestnanost-mesacne-statistiky/2020.html?page_id=971502"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for link in soup.select('a[href*=".xls"]'):
    print(link["class"], link["href"])
```

Prints:

```
['file-id-1059252'] https://www.upsvr.gov.sk/buxus/docs/statistic/mesacne/2020/MS_2012.xlsx
['file-id-1050892'] https://www.upsvr.gov.sk/buxus/docs/statistic/mesacne/2020/MS_2011.xlsx
['file-id-1042979'] https://www.upsvr.gov.sk/buxus/docs/statistic/mesacne/2020/MS_2010.xlsx
['file-id-1034316'] https://www.upsvr.gov.sk/buxus/docs/statistic/mesacne/2020/MS_2009_okresy.xlsx
['file-id-1027296'] https://www.upsvr.gov.sk/buxus/docs/statistic/mesacne/2020/MS_2008_okresy.xlsx
['file-id-1021527'] https://www.upsvr.gov.sk/buxus/docs/statistic/mesacne/2020/MS_2007_okresy.xlsx
['file-id-1015636'] https://www.upsvr.gov.sk/buxus/docs/statistic/mesacne/2020/MS_2006_okresy.xlsx
['file-id-1009682'] https://www.upsvr.gov.sk/buxus/docs/statistic/mesacne/2020/MS_maj2020_okresy.xlsx
['file-id-1002749'] https://www.upsvr.gov.sk/buxus/docs/statistic/mesacne/2020/MS_apr2020_okresy.xlsx
['file-id-995793'] https://www.upsvr.gov.sk/buxus/docs/statistic/mesacne/2020/MS_mar_2020_okresy.xlsx
['file-id-983937'] https://www.upsvr.gov.sk/buxus/docs/statistic/mesacne/2020/MS_2002_okresy.xlsx
['file-id-971509'] https://www.upsvr.gov.sk/buxus/docs/statistic/mesacne/2020/MS_2001.xlsx
```

Comment: Cheers Andy! This looks better.